# yo angular-fullstack:endpoint message does not generate message.socket.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, yeoman, angular-fullstack

yo angular-fullstack:endpoint shopPacket does not generate shopPacket.socket.js

I tried to update yo angular full stack generator but still does not work

````
yo angular-fullstack:endpoint shopPacket
? What will the url of your endpoint be? /api/shopPackets
   create server/api/shopPacket/shopPacket.controller.js
   create server/api/shopPacket/shopPacket.events.js
   create server/api/shopPacket/shopPacket.integration.js
   create server/api/shopPacket/shopPacket.model.js
   create server/api/shopPacket/index.js
   create server/api/shopPacket/index.spec.js```
````

it should generate

```
create server/api/shopPacket/shopPacket.socket.js
```

like before
is there an option I need to add in  order to produce it like 
this link: 
https://angular-fullstack.github.io/generators/endpoint/```

OS version/details: macos mojave 10.14.4

Node version: 10.15.1

npm version: 6.4.1

Version of yo : 2..0.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

socket.js file was not generated as the last angular-fullstack does not use [socketio](https://socket.io/) but changed by [primus](https://github.com/cayasso/primus.io) so I've installed the last version of angullar full stack with a lot of broken changes.